# Web API Async Upload with XmlHttpRequest to get progress

Tags: asynchronous, upload, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

I'm trying to drag and drop file upload with a progress bar.

I have a div which is listening to files being dropped on which is working perfectly. 
I'm then..

```
//Setting up a XmlHttpRequest 
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Open connection
xhr.open("post", "api/ImageUpload", true);

// Set appropriate headers
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", uf.type);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", uf.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", uf.size);
```

This sends fine, with the stream as the body of the request to the Web API (not async).

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public string Post()
{
    Stream stream =  HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
    String filename = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];

    FileModel file = uploadService.UploadFile(stream, filename);
    return file.Id.ToString();
 }
```

I'm trying to chance the request to "public async Task< string> Post(){ }

If the method was using a multipart form on the page instead of XmlHttpRequest I would have used "await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)" but this doesn't seem to be populated at the time I need it.

So what is the correct was to handle and an Async call from XmlHttpRequest on a Web API in order to record progress during the request with XHR's progress event?

I have looked at a great deal of pages so far to find a solution but this is the page I have used primarily.
http://robertnyman.com/html5/fileapi-upload/fileapi-upload.html

Thanks for any help
Oliver

Answer (score 2):

It looks like someone else had the same question with you and got an answer yet. please have a look at [ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703219/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-ajax-file-upload).
And here is an example from microsoft http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2.

I combined the two above solution together and worked for me (just adjust a little bit)

1. one line change in Javascritp

   xhr.open("post", "api/upload", true);
2. Save the file using stream

> ```
> public class UploadController : ApiController
> {
>     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
>     {
>         string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
>         var fileName = Path.Combine(root, Request.Headers.GetValues("X-File-Name").First());
>         try
>         {
>             var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
>             await Request.Content.CopyToAsync(writer.BaseStream);
>             writer.Close();
>             return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
>         }
>         catch (System.Exception e)
>         {
>             return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sadly I had already seen the 2 links.