# how to upload a file to asp.net core backend with http

Tags: asp.net-web-api, file-upload, http-post

Now I use Asp.net core as the server framework. I want to know how to upload a file to an Asp.net core server? I use web api but not the web application. So form submit is no use. The code below doesn't work.

```
[HttpPost("uploadImage/{accountGuid}")]
public async Task<string> UploadTargetImage(ICollection<IFormFile> files,Guid accountGuid)
{   
     if (files == null) throw new Exception("File is null");
     if (files.Count == 0) throw new Exception("File is empty");
}
```

I use fiddler to test the API. Like below:
[see the fiddler post image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ8cU.png)

The result of api is File is empty.So the server didn't get the post file. 
What should I do? It puzzles me for a long time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api ajax file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703219/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 1):

I hava just fix it! The input name in POST must be the same as method param in ASP.NET.